# Is there a process to become a Shia Muslim from Sunni Muslim?

Tags: sunni, shiism, conversion, bohra

I'm currently a teen Sunni Muslim who wants to become a Shia. I have researched myself and found that my heart is on the Shia side of Islam and I agree with more of the Shia side. Although is there a process of becoming a Shia Muslim? My family is Sunni although I do not want to tell them yet. But I want to start living my life as a Shia Muslim e.g. Praying, Reading The Quran, etc.

Comment: charged questions are not welcomed on ISE. So I recommend you take a better approach. However see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there seem to be several items that you ought to pay heed to them (and factually perform them) to be a Shia Muslims, such as:

- Believing in Allah (the oneness of God) (which is common between
  Shia/Sunni)
- Believing that Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) is the apostle of Allah (which
  is common between Shia/Sunni)

And actually Saying Shahadatayn (which is common between Shia/Sunni)...

**Likewise, believing that Ali (a.s.) is the successor of the Prophet (peace be upon him and his household) (and also, other Shia Imams who...)**

**And following other Shia beliefs and practices, such as manner of Salah (saying-prayer), and so forth.**

---

As another helpful issue(s):

> You must believe in the Shia fundamentals of faith with your own
>   insight and understanding. The Shia believe in five principles such as
>   the Oneness of God, Prophet-hood of the Last Prophet (S),
>   Resurrection, Divine Justice and Imamate.

---

**Source and more accurate matters:**

[www.shiachat.com](http://www.shiachat.com/forum/topic/234981232-how-to-convert-to-a-shia-muslim/)

[www.al-islam.org](https://www.al-islam.org/search/site/converting)

[www.maaref.porsemani.ir](http://www.maaref.porsemani.ir/node/1262)

Answer (score 1):

You keep your family and Sunni friends, you don't go to them with your new ideology of Islam. If they had questions then you answer. If not be silent.

In addition: 
You have already said the *shahadatyn* so you were a Muslim and still will be.

You need to acknowledge the existence of Imam Mahdi as your current Imam *(من لم یعرف امامه مات میته جاهلیه)* and try to follow his way of living. In addition, you need to study and understand religion if you can't do that then you need to find yourself a marja' like what many others do and then learn their different ahkam (religious orders). Turning into a Shia may significantly change the way you think + lot's of *small* changes in Ahkam, like in way of prayers, wudu, time of adhan, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a Shia you should say:

اشهد ان لا اله الا الله، اشهد ان محمد رسول الله، اشهد ان علی ولی الله

If you said, you are a Shia.